# Pandas allocation / delegation of unique values in a dataframe column to a user from a list

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a Dataframe of email addresses with their domains. I have a list of users 1-5

```
users = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

I need to allocate each unique domain to a user id, I need to ensure that multiples of the same domain are always allocated to the same user id, however the individual domains can be allocated to any user id as long as these somewhat evenly distributed across the users.

My Dataframe:

```
   email                  first_name    last_name     domain          
0  krusty@gmail.com       Herschel      Krustofsky    gmail.com       
1  bob@hotmail.com        Robert        Terwilliger   hotmail.com     
2  h.simpson@email.com    Homer         Simpson       email.com       
3  bsimpson@gmail.com     Bart          Simpson       gmail.com       
4  moe@moestavern.com     Moe           Szyslak       moestavern.com   
5  marge@simpson.net      Marge         Simpson       simpson.net     
6  lisa.simpson@sax.com   Lisa          Simpson       sax.com         
7  itchy@hotmail.com      Itchy         And           hotmail.com     
8  scratchy@work.net      Scratchy      Show          work.net        
9  maggie@hotmail.com     Maggie        Simpson       hotmail.com     
10 skinner@teacher.net    Seymour       Skinner       teacher.net
```

My desired outcome.

```
   email                  first_name    last_name     domain           user_id
0  krusty@gmail.com       Herschel      Krustofsky    gmail.com        1
1  bob@hotmail.com        Robert        Terwilliger   hotmail.com      2
2  h.simpson@email.com    Homer         Simpson       email.com        3
3  bsimpson@gmail.com     Bart          Simpson       gmail.com        1
4  moe@moestavern.com     Moe           Szyslak       moestavern.com   4
5  marge@simpson.net      Marge         Simpson       simpson.net      5
6  lisa.simpson@sax.com   Lisa          Simpson       sax.com          1
7  itchy@hotmail.com      Itchy         And           hotmail.com      2
8  scratchy@work.net      Scratchy      Show          work.net         3
9  maggie@hotmail.com     Maggie        Simpson       hotmail.com      2
10 skinner@teacher.net    Seymour       Skinner       teacher.net      4
```

Incrementing the user id might not be the best approach as my example user 5 seems low in comparison?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, to get the unique domains as a dataframe:

```
unique = pd.DataFrame(df['domain'].drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True))

           domain
0       gmail.com
1     hotmail.com
2       email.com
3  moestavern.com
4     simpson.net
5         sax.com
6        work.net
7     teacher.net
```

Then using numpy with a list of users, you can assign each domain one of the 5 users:

```
IDs = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
unique['user_id'] = np.resize(IDs, unique.shape[0])

               domain  user_id
0       gmail.com        1
1     hotmail.com        2
2       email.com        3
3  moestavern.com        4
4     simpson.net        5
5         sax.com        1
6        work.net        2
7     teacher.net        3
```

You can then merge on this to get the id for each row:

```
df.merge(unique, on='domain')
```

or using a dictionary with replace:

```
ids = {unique.loc[i, 'domain']:unique.loc[i, 'user_id'] for i in range(len(unique))}
    df['user_id'] = df['domain'].replace(ids)


   email                  first_name    last_name     domain           user_id
0  krusty@gmail.com       Herschel      Krustofsky    gmail.com        1
1  bob@hotmail.com        Robert        Terwilliger   hotmail.com      2
2  h.simpson@email.com    Homer         Simpson       email.com        3
3  bsimpson@gmail.com     Bart          Simpson       gmail.com        1
4  moe@moestavern.com     Moe           Szyslak       moestavern.com   4
5  marge@simpson.net      Marge         Simpson       simpson.net      5
6  lisa.simpson@sax.com   Lisa          Simpson       sax.com          1
7  itchy@hotmail.com      Itchy         And           hotmail.com      2
8  scratchy@work.net      Scratchy      Show          work.net         2
9  maggie@hotmail.com     Maggie        Simpson       hotmail.com      2
10 skinner@teacher.net    Seymour       Skinner       teacher.net      3
```

(This doesn't fully match your example, so please tell me if I've missed something).

Full code:

```
unique = pd.DataFrame(df['domain'].drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True))
IDs = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
unique['user_id'] = np.resize(IDs, unique.shape[0])
ids = {unique.loc[i, 'domain']:unique.loc[i, 'user_id'] for i in range(len(unique))}
df['user_id'] = df['domain'].replace(ids)
```

Comment: it is certainly on the right track, thank you. However one issue is I only have 5 users 1-5 and i need to allocate them these domains. Your logic is sound but it goes up to 8 users, the user is not the domain, the user is from another list of who would be managing the account.

Comment: @a.WOL7 have updated the answer

Comment: that did it, thank you so much. Accepting this as the answer.